# Getting function argument value from PHP extension in c++

Tags: php, c++, php-extension, php-internals

I have created php extension in c++.In version php 5.6 can able to get currently executed function details. I was getting the arguments value as follows,

```
if (real_execute_data->function_state.arguments)
    {
        void **p = real_execute_data->function_state.arguments;
        int arg_count = (int)(zend_uintptr_t)* p;

        zval *argument_element;
        for (i = 0; i < arg_count; i++)
        {
            argument_element = (zval*)*(p - (arg_count - i));
            // here can reads the value from argument_element 
        }
    }
```

In version Php 7.2,I can't find the function_state structure inside of Zend_execute_data.I tried with  _zend_arg_info structure, it gives function argument variable names,not the values.
How can i get the function arguments value in php 7 above?

Comment: Have you checked https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I got it.
We can get the function arguments in php 7 and above as follows(zend_execute_data *real_execute_data),

```
 int arg_count = ZEND_CALL_NUM_ARGS(real_execute_data);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= arg_count; i++)
    {
        zval *argument_element = ZEND_CALL_ARG(real_execute_data, i);
        // we can reads the argument value from "argument_element".
    }
```